# "Draw over other apps" change listener?

Tags: android

In my application I have the necessity to know when the user grants the "Draw over other apps" permission. Is there a way to know it? 
Since I can only send the user to the settings page to enable it using the Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION intent action, I'd expect a system broadcast or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't a system broadcast, but you can use [canDrawOverlays (Context context)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#canDrawOverlays(android.content.Context)):

> An app can use this method to check if it is currently allowed to draw
>   on top of other apps. In order to be allowed to do so, an app must
>   first declare the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission in its manifest. If
>   it is currently disallowed, it can prompt the user to grant it this
>   capability through a management UI by sending an Intent with action
>   ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION.

You can check it directly in your `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            //Permission is granted
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this would be a good solution if I'd need to know as soon as I re-enter the app. But in my specific case I'd like to know it as soon as the settings changes from "off" to "on".

Comment: @Santacrab did you find a solution for this? I need the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately not.